# What is the Rails convention for sending form data to a URL dependent on form value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, input, controller, routes

I would like a form submitted at the url

```
/index/fruit
```

to submit the form data to

```
/index/:identifier
```

where :identifier is determined by a value of the form

What is the rails convention in this instance?
Is there a way to achieve this without a controller level redirect or javascript-updating the submit URL?

***routes.rb***

```
match 'smasher(/:action(/:id))', :controller => "customcontroller", :as => :smasher, :defaults => { :action => :index, :id => :fruit }
```

***index.html.erb***

```
<%= semantic_form_for :d, :url => smasher_path,  :html => { :method => :get } do |f| %>
  ... form data ... 
  <%= f.input :identifier, :as => :hidden %>
<% end %>
```

My current implementation is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435746/1758006)

Comment: change the url of the form dynamically using javascript and a listener to the "identifier" input?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that does not penalise the javascriptless

Comment: javascript might be the best way to go.  but dont worry its not alot.

Answer (score 1):

There's isn't really a "convention" for this, but rather one of those things where there's more than one way to do it.

One way that you could do it is still send the form to one and only one action within the controller, but then delegate *in the controller* which action to go to, like this:

```
def smasher
  if params[:identifier] == 'this'
    smash_this!
  else
    smash_that!
  end
end

def smash_this!
  # code goes here
end

def smash_that!
  # code goes here
end
```

Comment: My issue isn't handling the response, but rather, making sure the URL reflects the submitted form value.

Comment: Why would it be necessary for the URL to reflect the submitted form value?

Comment: @OhNoezWoez you should take a closer look at this answer, as it is the alternative to javascript you asked for

Comment: I am currently delegating in the controller, however it does not answer the question in that I specifically want a particular URL to be displayed that is dependent on one of the form fields. It is the :id value I am concerned with, rather than the :action. My current workaround for this is to redirect_to based on the form value passed. But I am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the javascript version (though technically its all on an *erb* html template), if you're feeling up to it.

```
<%= f.input :identifier, :as => :hidden, :onchange => "$(this).setAction()" %>

<script>
// While you can this script block here within your erb template
// but best practice says you should have it included somehow within `<head></head>` 
$(function() {

    //create a method on the Jquery Object to adjust the action of the form
    $.fn.setAction = function() {
        var form = $(this).parents('form').first();
        var action = form.attr('action')
        form.attr('action', action.substr( 0, action.lastIndexOf('/')+1 ) + $(this).val());
    }
});
</script>
```

Heres the **pure javascript version:**

```
$(function() {

    //create a method on the Jquery Object to adjust the action of the form
    $.fn.setAction = function() {
        var form = $(this).parents('form').first();
        var action = form.attr('action')
        form.attr('action', action.substr( 0, action.lastIndexOf('/')+1 ) + $(this).val());
    }

    //we gotta bind the onchange here
    $('input[name="identifier"]').change($.fn.setAction);          

});
```